# Groovy syntax and variable it?

Tags: groovy, spock

```
1 * subject.statusRepository.save({
    it.Id == request.Id
    it.location == location
    it.team == statusExisting.getTeam()
    it.statusEnum == StatusEnum.Status.W
})
```

What is this groovy syntax (I use it in Spock).
I don't know what is "it" Variable.
and I don't understand the JSON like syntax as parameter of save .

Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure what you are really asking, but all of those expressions inside of the closure (`it.Id == request.Id`, `it.location == location`) don't appear to be doing anything other than comparing items to each other and then ignoring the result (`true` or `false`).  Is that your intent?

Comment: Toni: feedback, please. I think that ignoring comments and answers without providing any feedback is quite impolite. There are people here who spend their private time to help others for free. You ought to show some appreciation. Neither did you mark any answer as accepted, nor did you ask follow-up questions or describe what might be wrong with those answers.

Answer (score 1):

*@Jeff Scott Brown* already correctly explained how Groovy closures work. I am going to explain the Spock testing DSL specifics on top of that, because he does not seem to know about them:

`1 * subject.statusRepository.save(...)` means to verify that the `save` method is called exactly once as specified inside the argument constraint `(...)`. You want to read about [**cardinality**](https://spockframework.org/spock/docs/2.1/all_in_one.html#_cardinality) in Spock in order to understand `1 *`.

```java
{
    it.Id == request.Id
    it.location == location
    it.team == statusExisting.getTeam()
    it.statusEnum == StatusEnum.Status.W
}
```

is an [**argument constraint**](https://spockframework.org/spock/docs/2.1/all_in_one.html#_argument_constraints) for the first method argument, specifying conditions that argument needs to comply with for a positive match.

The four lines of code are called **conditions**. They are syntactic sugar or shorthands for assertions and one of the basic building blocks of the Spock DSL. They are part of what makes writing and reading Spock tests to elegant, expressive and intuitive.

I strongly recommend you to learn some basic Groovy syntax and also read the Spock manual. Stack Overflow is not meant to be your shortcut for skipping the learning part of using a new tool or a new language.

Here is a simplified [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) version of your situation:

```java
class Data {
    def Id
    def location
}
```

```java
class Subject {
    def save(Data data) {}

    def doSomething() {
        save(new Data(Id: 1234, location: 'somewhere'))
    }
}
```

```java
class MySpec extends Specification {
    def test() {
        given:
        Subject subject = Spy()

        when:
        subject.doSomething()

        then:
        1 * subject.save({
            it.Id == 1234
            it.location == 'somewhere'
        })
    }
}
```

Try it in the [Groovy Web Console](https://gwc-experiment.appspot.com/?g=groovy_2_5&codez=eJxVT8sOgjAQPNOv2JvUGBMfJxJuXjh44gtqu0CNFmPXByH8u7VAgT203e7Mzoy8CWvhJEhAy8CVwgIyFZ63WgrStWEdY9Jj89flipJmcCveGPsVyh0cWocdZ6rO6ztSpU0Z84HzL88x-PHScaYS2O0Px03QS2BlHfFT4RNXnHteN5k4N_kDJeCX0CjnyTW60D115ozQ0kK21G80SWjHLHa4U7epiTkLAKc_gw-w7SLUBKYFeAfrQPBpexdRpGmbKUhTn3j6G5P_J7PsLIq6Kf4PYHV4DA).

Just change a value in the `Data` constructor call or in the argument constraint condition in order to see the test fail.

Answer (score 0):

"JSON like syntax as parameter" called [closure](https://groovy-lang.org/closures.html) In this article you will also find an explanation of implicit `it` parameter that is often used in the closures.